# Little problem with ajax. Error-function is executed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have a little problem with ajax and mysql.
I want to save same data to a database via ajax.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : url_save,
    async : false,
    data : { item : nr, var : text },
    success: function(result_save){  
        if (result_save.includes('Error')) { 
          alert("!!!  Error  !!!");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("!!!  Error  !!!");
    }
});
```

My PHP-File looks like:
    PHP:

```
<?php
    require "config.inc.php";
$db = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME) or die ('Error');
$db->set_charset("utf8");
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl (item, var) VALUES ('$_POST[item]','$_POST[var]')";
if (!mysqli_query($db,$sql))
{
    return 'Error';
    die();
}

mysql_close($db);
return 'i.O.';
?>
```

It saves to the database, but the error-function of ajax is executed every time. What is wrong?

Comment: You may have problem with var as key in object because it's keyword, try `'var': text}` this may fail in IE not sure of other browsers, Chrome works fine.

Comment: First check which error you get probably the one in success. Because `'error'.includes('error')` is true.

Comment: You just return the word error both in php and in the js code when something goes wrong preventing you from finding out what has gone wrong. Log the proper error message and you will be a lot wiser as to what's going on.

Comment: No, its the error of error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("!!!  Error  !!!");
    }. In the real code, that is an other message.

Comment: You need to quote your $_POST key in your SQL command: `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (item, var) VALUES ('{$_POST['item']}','{$_POST['var']}')";`

Comment: Also, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, please consider using mysqli prepare statement.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

- jcubic is correct- you don't want to use a JS keyword as a parameter name.
- catcon is also correct.  Using a prepared statement is *FAR* preferable to reading the variable directly into your SQL text.
- Even if mysqli_query() returns 0, you still want to do a mysql_close($db), don't you?
- You would also like to know the specific error, wouldn't you?

SUGGESTION:

PHP:

```
<?php
  require "config.inc.php";
  $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (item, var) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST[item_id], $_POST[item_value]);
  if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    $result =  "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . "): " . $stmt->error;
  }
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
  return ($result) ? 'Success' : $result;
  ...
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : url_save,
    async : false,
    data : { item_id: nr, item_value: text },
    success: function(result_save){  
        if (result_save === 'Success') {
          console.log('Insert was successful', nr, value);
        } else {
          alert('mySql Error: ', JSON.stringify(result_save));
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('XHR Exception: ' + textStatus + ', ' + JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
    }
});
```